# Command Line Arguments in Imported Python Modules

Tags: python, command-line

This is more a question of coding style, but I have a script that processes a particular file (or set of files). It would be nice to allow the user to provide those files as command-line arguments. Of course, it's possible that the user forgets to provide these or the filenames are invalid, so I have to introduce a try/except here.

Problem is, someone may want to import my module in the future. But, I don't know what command line arguments *that* program may require. Also, if an error is thrown when my module access the command-line argument, it seems like it would be better handled by the script that is importing my module. However, my script still needs to be able to cope as a stand-alone if an error is thrown.

Is there a smart way around this problem, or is the best solution just to abandon command-line arguments altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual procedure:

```
import sys

def main(*files):
    # your program's logic goes here

if __name__ == "__main__": #i.e. run directly
    try:
        main(*sys.argv[1:])
    except IOError:
        handle_error()
```

If imported, `__name__` will be != `"__main__"`, thus nothing actually happens and the importer can call `main(file1, file2)`. But if this script is the main script (i.e. not imported), it will just do what it does now, only in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your file is being run or if it's imported thus:

```
def myFunction(file):
  #do stuff to file

if __name__ == '__main__':
  #I have not been imported!
  try:
    file = sys.argv[1]
  except:
    print "Usage: myFile.py file"
    sys.exit()
  myFunction(file)
```